# Adding a new Azure table

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have created a mobile service application on the old Azure management page, where I was able to manually add a table from the web interface. I could then synchronize my local storage and it would create the necessary columns/etc.

Now that I have migrated my application to an app service application, the web management interface on the new portal doesn't have anywhere to add a table (that I can find). I am successfully connected to the Azure database in Visual Studio, and I manually created a new table called `Address`. I have inserted an address into my local database, but now when I try to sync I get an error:

> Error: Table 'Address' does not exist.

I know that it does exist, because I am looking at it in my Visual Studio SQL Server Object Explorer. I am using the same schema and everything, and I know my application is connected to the right database. I verified this by deleting all of my data from both local and remote storage, and then adding a new item to one of the existing tables, and then synced, and both databases now match.

It was very easy to add a new table on the old Azure management page, but not so much anymore. I have searched online for this issue, but wasn't able to find an answer to my situation. Here is what the newly created table looks like in my Explorer:
[image: screenshot]

I simply manually created the fields that would normally be created by the web interface. I verified that all of the datatypes match, etc. But for some reason, I still get that same `Table 'Address' does not exist` error when I try to sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a new table go to azure portal,
click app serices,
click settings,
scroll down to easy tables,
and you will then see a add icon in the new window

also I will encourage you to download microsft sql management studio and connect to server and mange it that way

a lot easier to use than visual studio

Comment: Wow, that easy tables was buried. Thanks for the tip @David. I do have Management Studio as well, I just occasionally like to browse from within the project just for simplicity, but I agree - Management Studio is much better for managing the database.

Comment: any idea why adding a new table from Visual Studio wouldn't show up on the portal, though?

Comment: my guess is some linking between mobile services and table